# open url with local notification ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have been searching around for a while trying to find an answer but I cant seem to find one. What I am trying to do is have my app send a local notification when the app is running in the background and when the user opens the notification it will take them to a website. I have it all set up but it keeps opening the app instead of going to the website.

My question is, is this even possible to do? And if so could you please see where i am going wrong with my code below? Thank you for your help.

CODE:

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *futureDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:3];
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = futureDate;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Visit Our Website for more info";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];

    if ( [notifyAlarm.alertBody isEqualToString:@"Visit Our Website for more info"] ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.bluemoonstudios.com.au"]];
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Your Business Logic

```
-(void)scheduleNotificationForDate:(NSDate *)fireDate{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertAction = @"View";
    notification.alertBody = @"New Message Received";
    notification.userInfo = @{@"SiteURLKey": @"http://www.google.com"};
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

in your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if(notification != nil){
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"SiteURLKey"]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:siteURL];
    }
}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"SiteURLKey"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:siteURL];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, how do i implement this with the code i already have shown above? or is this separate to that?

Comment: Thank you again, but where do you mean by "In Your Business Logic"? Im sorry but Im still new at this. Thank you for understanding and your help

Comment: paste that function in your ViewController and call it from any IBAction you defined.
e.g
[self scheduleNotificationForDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: Ok, i understand now, thank you. But now it only goes to the website if I press the button in my view controller. What i am trying to achieve is when the app is closed and you receive the notification, when you swipe the notification i want it to go directly to the website and not open the app at all. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's not possible in Official iOS SDK. Swiping / tapping on notification banner would open up the app any way. Try to explore application state checks i.e Active / InActive to use it in didReceiveLocalNotification method.

Comment: Great Thanks for all your help and quick responses. I very much appreciate it.