# Opening web page using LocalNotification

Tags: xcode, ibeacon

I'm creating an iBeacon app that opens a web page through a notification on my device whenever it enters the beacon region. Is there anyway to do it with my current code below which uses if-else loop?

Any help is kindly appreciated!

```
 UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
{

}
else if (state == CLRegionStateOutside)
{
    notification.alertBody = @"Outside region";
}
    else
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276829/open-url-with-local-notification-ios).  It has example code showing how to do just what you want.

You just need to move the code creating the notification inside your callback method above.